# Interfaces and namespaces in PHP

Tags: php

I have started to use interfaces. They are just handy. But I'm thinking of employing my namespaces beside them. I need to have a certain namespace scheme. Shall the interface be defined in the same namespace that the class is going to implement?

Comment: who has voted me down?

Answer (score 1):

No you can define an interface in a namespace and a class in another

Comment: would you please edit your explanation and add a bit more explanation